# Why does current_page? return a `no route error` when I am doing it on a fully managed resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncontroller

I have the following route:

```
  resources :profiles do
    member do
      patch :speed_rating
      patch :dribbling_rating
      patch :passing_rating
      patch :tackling_rating
      post :favorite
      post :unfavorite
    end
    collection do
      get :autocomplete
    end
  end
```

That generates the following route that I am interested in:

```
# truncated for brevity
profiles_path  GET  /profiles(.:format)  profiles#index

profile_path  GET   /profiles/:id(.:format)  profiles#show
```

In my `application.html.erb`, I have this:

```
    <% if current_page?(controller: "profiles", action: "show")%>
      <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg">
    <% else %>
      <div id="page-wrapper" class="image-bg">
    <% end %>
```

When I go to my `Profiles#Show` it works fine, but when I go to my `Profiles#Index` (aka my root_path), I get something else:

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2016-11-07 16:52:01 -0500
  User Load (1.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Processing by ProfilesController#index as HTML
  Role Load (4.8ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 7]]
  Role Load (12.9ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'coach') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 7]]
  Role Load (6.7ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'player') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 7]]
   (4.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)) OR ((roles.name = 'coach') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 7]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'player') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 7]]
   (2.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'coach') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)) OR ((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 7]]
  Profile Search (23.5ms)  curl http://localhost:9200/profiles_development/_search?pretty -d '{"query":{"match_all":{}},"size":1000,"from":0,"timeout":"11s","_source":false}'
  Tournament Load (2.7ms)  SELECT  "tournaments".* FROM "tournaments" ORDER BY "tournaments"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering profiles/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Profile Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."id" IN (14, 22, 12, 21, 9, 5, 4, 15, 6, 7, 16, 18, 13, 23, 17)
Read fragment views//profiles/14-20161105042425134917/profiles/22-20161106175803133611/profiles/12-20161101225114614189/profiles/21-20161103035514173735/profiles/9-20161104221706306433/profiles/5-20161105043153971213/profiles/4-20161103035528589634/profiles/15-20161029013919242687/profiles/6-20161105043216951643/profiles/7-20161101001052922220/profiles/16-20161029020526832889/profiles/18-20161101223838805685/profiles/13-20161104221749051281/profiles/23-20161104062851335443/profiles/17-20161105043606243802/af785066fd895798884eea54748241db (0.1ms)
  Rendered profiles/index.html.erb within layouts/application (12.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 379ms (ActiveRecord: 36.4ms)


ActionController::UrlGenerationError - No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles"}:
```

**Edit 1**

For the record, the following works with no issues:

```
<% if (controller_name.eql? "profiles") && (action_name.eql? "show") %>
```

Comment: :controller=>"profile"
Shouldn't it be "profiles"?

Comment: @EricDuminil it is. My bad. I was testing whether or not it mattered if I used `current_page?(controller: "profile")` and I pasted the wrong log output. Fixed now. Also, for the record, it didn't matter. Neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at `current_page?` [source code](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/current_page%3F) you'll realize it uses `url_for`, which actually needs valid options to build a URL and match with the one you see at the address bar.

`url_for(controller: "profiles", action: "show")` won't be able to find that route without an `:id`. If you try using `current_page?(controller: "profiles", action: "show", id: 1)` you'll see that the error won't be raised.

`current_page` isn't your best option for this job because it's designed to test for a perfect match, including other query string parameters like:

```
 # http://www.example.com/shop/checkout?order=desc&page=1
 current_page?(controller: 'shop', action: 'checkout', order: 'desc', page: '1')
```

In your particular case, you'd like it to match any page rendering the show action. I think the solution you presented in your **Edit 1** is suitable. You can always wrap it up in your own helper if you want to clean it up.